# Clipping AdornerLayer

Tags: wpf, adorner, adornerlayer

I have a `PanZoomImage` class defined like this:

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" Name="border" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Canvas Name="canvas">
        <Image Name="image" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" Stretch="None" 
           Source="{Binding Path=Source}"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="image_MouseLeftButtonDown"
           MouseLeftButtonUp="image_MouseLeftButtonUp"
           MouseMove="image_MouseMove"
           MouseWheel="image_MouseWheel"
           Loaded="image_Loaded">
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Sometimes I want to display Adorners on the image so I have a property that gives me the `AdornerLayer` for the image:

```
public AdornerLayer Adorners
{
    get
    {
        return AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(image);
    }
}
```

I use this property to add different adorners to the image. The problem is that when I pan or zoom the image, the aodrners are not clipped and are displayed outside the control that holds the `PanZoomImage`, like this:
[image: No clipping]

I tried several solutions:

I tried setting `ClipToBounds=True` for the border, the canvas and the image.

I tried setting `ClipToBounds=True` for the `AdornerLayer` and for each Adorner individually.

I tried setting a Clip Geometry in Adorner's OnRender.

I also noticed there's a `IsClipEnabled` property to Adorner but when I tried setting it to true, I kept getting a NullReferenceException (even though the Adorner was definitely not null)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `IsClipEnabled` property works. The `NullPointerException` is thrown if the adorned control has no parent. You have to place the control into some container before setting `IsClipEnabled`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the secret source was to:

1. Set `IsClipEnabled=true` on the Adorner
2. Set `ClipToBounds=true` on the adorned element